# The requested URL is not downloading from vagrantup

Tags: vagrant-provision

```
$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Box 'centos/7' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...

       default: Box Provider: virtualbox

       default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'centos/7'

    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/centos/7

==> default: Adding box 'centos/7' (v1905.1) for provider: virtualbox

    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/centos/boxes/7/versions/1905.1/providers/virtualbox.box

==> default: Box download is resuming from prior download progress

    default: Download redirected to host: cloud.centos.org

    default:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 416
```